# Having readily available books, links, topics about English Language (basics) here on ELL

Tags: feature-request

There must have been many questions asking about learning English language from the best resources. Especially non-native speakers wonder **which one** is better and preferable.

Since MSM (mainstream media) in non-native speaking countries uses local English, it's quite difficult for non-native speakers to learn International English. It is worth nothing that many ***consider*** MSM as the most authentic source. But, it's not.

I seek your opinion on ***providing*** some standard books available to download here. It could be **free or priced** depending on the sources or agreement we manage.

We may ask the publishers to provide free downloads in the interest of the users worldwide *(anyway, almost all books are available to download from other links as nothing is impossible on the Internet!)*.

### At least some links -readily available?

Something is better than nothing. At least we can provide some link readily available? Say --

English Grammar Guide - [EduFind (BBC links it)](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/english-grammar-guide/).

I would be happy seeing these links on a common page or maybe, we can come up with some structured page easy to navigate and browse by the new users. For instance,

### Under the page of Adjective

> [Adjective order](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) 
>  [Adjective placement](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/using-adjectives-english/) 
>  and so on...

Let us unite and provide the links that most of us agree (say -- BBC, Cambridge, Swan, Oxford etc. As natives, you may know better) and provide the links to the new users here. This way, ELL will become a ***complete guide*** to the language. Said that, if you are *here,* you don't need to go anywhere for anything including *genuine* sources.

I know that there are **exceptions** and it requires *in-depth* knowledge of the language. But the users (especially new) on ELL are in need to learn the 'normal' things first, and *then* exceptions or what we may say *core English*. Once they are thorough with the basics, they'd learn further as on ELU.

For this, we may have 'English Guide for Basic Knowledge' under which, we may start putting chapters, or directly downloadable books, or simple links to concerned topics **but** everything in a structured way as I said in my example of *adjectives*.

The best benefit of this initiative is on this site, I find users from all across the world and each one of us knows at least 2-3 *genuine* sources of learning the language. Why not (especially seniors here) benefit the new users or the community here?

Just seeking an opinion. Your comment/answers are welcomed.

Comment: Could you tell us what 'MSM' is?

Comment: Oh. It's *main stream media*. @snailboat

Comment: It's interesting that you think of "basics" as "the 'normal' things", and "exceptions" as "core English", and advanced English as (or on) ELU.

Comment: Yes. Basic/normal things to *learn* the usage of ['inasmuch'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62978/in-inasmuch-what-did-in-as-much-mean/62983#62983) and 'core English' as history or etymology behind it. So, I'd like to have a page on uses of such things here on ELL! @DamkerngT.

Comment: I don't understand how this might be different from our resources thread with a different sort of index.

Answer (score 5):

Would it be useful to have these in tag wikis instead? That way it is community-editable but still goes through peer review (unless you have the reputation), whereas here on meta, either you can edit it, or you can't, and while there is *some* peer review in that the post owner gets notified, it's probably not fair to leave it to them to rollback any changes made that are unsuitable.

Also, in having them in tag wikis, you're able to make detailed reference to issues that arise repeatedly and either link to great answers, or quote parts of texts that address them.

Comment: Creating 'tags' would typically address 'every aspect' of the topic. It may then become complex. I want plain reference, one click reference (say, page about adjective which includes **general** things about adjective) to most of the grammar topics.

Comment: That's what I mean, though. We have the [tag:adjective] tag. You click on it, and then there's a whole section that people don't always look at - which we can use to create a wonderful resource.

Comment: But that makes 50X7 entries. People, as you said, are not *tend* to visit them all. But [the presentation like this](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/adjectives/) is more likely to be referred and used. Are you getting me?

Comment: I understand, but there's no reason we can't have something like that in the adjective tag, with a precis of the sub-topics, and a link to off-site resources. I'm not sure where you're proposing that we put these. In a meta post, somewhere?

Comment: Consider the [tag wiki for 'tense'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/tense/info), for instance. If we needed to, we could include links to off-site resources, or just improve what we already have.

Comment: I like the idea of improving the tag wikis. If a learner doesn't have a specific question about for example, past perfect tense, it would be great to encourage them to click on the tag and browse the questions and answers. I think if the tag wikis had information in them beyond a description of what they're used for, it would make the tags much more useful and encourage searching the site. We would have to get the word out somehow that the tags are more than just a way to categorize your question though.

Comment: Could use a community promotion ad to advertise them.

Comment: We should probably come up with a list of tags to focus on. Our most popular tag is grammar, which I think wouldn't be the best place to start.

Comment: Also, if we were closing as too broad, and one or more relevant tags have good wikis, that would be a good opportunity to promote them.

Comment: Why does it have to be one or the other? We can have a Meta thread that indexes and explains relevant terms and links to the appropriate tag wikis.